# Dynamic url value in spring 6 httpexchanges

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httpexchange

I am migrating my clients from Feign to spring 6 httpexchanges. With Feign it is possible to set the base url dynamically. However, I am not able to achieve this with httpexchanges. With httpexchanges an URI can be set. However, this will overwrite the whole path.

I've created the following client:

```
public interface MyClient {

    @GetExchange(value = "/some-path")
    String getData(URI baseUrl);
}
```

If I now call `getData(URI.create("http://some-url.com")` the resulting request is made to just `http://some-url.com`. Is it possible to call `http://some-url.com/some-path`?

I've also tried to set the base url as path variable

```
public interface MyClient {

    @GetExchange(value = "{baseUrl}/some-path")
    String getData(@PathVariable URI baseUrl);
}
```

However, this will encode my baseUrl and something like `http%3A%2F%2Fsome-url.com%2Fsome-path` is called.

Comment: Did you try to pass it as a String ?

Comment: Hi, I've testet your suggestion. However, it seems like `http%3A%2F%2Fsome-url.com%2Fsome-path` is still called

Comment: One more think, just replace : `String getData(@PathVariable URI baseUrl);` to `String getData(@PathVariable(name = "baseUrl") URI baseUrl);`

Comment: Yes sure i can name the path variable. However, this still leads to escaping of the base url

Comment: One more question, did you try to pass the url in method so: `getData(URI.create("http://some-url.com/some-path")); ` ?

Comment: Sure it works to set url with your path. However, for more complicated calls you lose the possibility to set some path segments via @pathvariable like
```public interface MyClient {

    @GetExchange(value = "/some-path/{path-variable}/some-thing")
    String getData(URI baseUrl, @PathVariable("path-variable") String pathVariable);
}
```
Therefore i would like to set the path directly in the httpexchange.

Comment: what if, you will try next one approach: in method signature declare something like this, `String getData(URI baseUrl, @PathVariable("id") Long variable);`  and invoke of this method `.getData(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/{id}"), 1L));`

Comment: I don't think, that `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/{id}` is a valid URI

Comment: just try it, in runtime {id} will be replaced with value from `@PathVariable` if i understood correct the documentation about httpexchanges

Comment: `URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/{id}")` does not work since `{id}` is not valid

Comment: did you replace my example about how it can be to your exact implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be possible with Spring 6.1 (Spring Boot 3.2)
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30935